# VBA error when trying to close IE after accessing intranet site

Tags: windows, excel, vba

The code below works fine if a internet site such as google is used. However, I need to access a work intranet site. When I do I get the following error, run-time error '-2147023179 (800706b5)': Automation error     The interface is unknown.

```
Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "INTRANET SITE"

Do While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
```

Please help. Thanks.

NOTE: If excel is ran as administrator then this works fine; however, I don't think its possible for excel to be ran as admin for just this one workbook.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Controlling IE local intranet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965032/excel-vba-controlling-ie-local-intranet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unchecking protected mode fixed the problem.

Also can use the following bit of code

```
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
```

Comment: I like the second option due to the fact that security isn't affected for when the user normally uses the internet.