# Excel VBA - Type mismatch and object does not support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have a very nerve wracking problem, the code worked just fine. After saving it and going back an hour after the code started to throw some errors at me. Type mismatch happens when I am checking if the element is present, if I comment the condition I get the "object does not support this property or method". Any ideas, what might cause this problem?

```
Sub Main()

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ieLogin ie
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    ieFilter ie
    
End Sub


Sub ieLogin(ie As Object)


  Const Url$ = "http://czpskmii0021.ls.ege.ds:50000/XMII/CM/SC_MAINTENANCE/Report/WorkOrderList.irpt"

    Dim UserName As String, Password As String, LoginData As Worksheet
    Set LoginData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    UserName = LoginData.Cells(1, "B").Value
    Password = LoginData.Cells(2, "B").Value


    With ie

        .navigate Url
        ieBusy ie
        .Visible = True

        Dim oUserName As Object
        Dim oPassword As Object
        Set oLogin = .document.getElementsByName("j_username")
        Set oPassword = .document.getElementsByName("j_password")
        
        If (.document.getElementById("logonuidfield")) Then
            oLogin.Value = UserName
            oPassword.Value = Password
        End If

        

    End With

End Sub

Sub ieFilter(ie As Object)
    
    With ie
        Dim OrderType As Object
        
        Set OrderType = .document.getElementById("selectOrderType")
        'OrderType.Value = "REPA"
    End With
    
    DoEvents
End Sub

Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you get an error? I'm wondering, that there a two lines with `set ie = ...` .

Comment: Have you reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370916/web-scraper-run-time-error-13-on-document-getelementbyid ?

Comment: I don't see where you submit the login form?  Maybe add `Option Explicit` and fix all the issues it flags up.

Comment: Are you on windows 11?

Comment: I noticed that you are not clicking any button to submit the login information. So it looks like currently, your code is not login to the site. After that, it immediately executes the line `ieFilter ie`.
If you are not login to the site and you try to use a filter then the filter might not available and could give you errors. You could debug the code and make sure that it is login and after that when the filter is available then it uses the filter. It might help you fix the said error.

Comment: I am on windows 10.  The part of the code where this is happening is when I am testing, if there is the login window. `If (.document.getElementById("logonuidfield")) Then` this is where I get the "Type mismatch", if I comment the condition I get error here `oLogin.Value = UserName` saying that "Object does not support this property or method"

Comment: `Set oClick = .document.getElementsByName("uidPasswordLogon")(0).Click` I edited the code, so It would click. Tried to comment the `ieFilter ie` but that did not change a thing.