# Run Time Error '91' : Object Variable or With Block not Set

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have been using below code and it is giving me an error that is `Run Time Error '91' : Object Variable or With Block not Set` I do not know why.

Earlier it was working fine but i do not know why an error is occur. I have tried other solutions searching `Copy URL from the first Search` but they also were not working.

error appear on this line `Set link = ecoll.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)`

If someone can provide alternate solution it will be great help. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

```
Sub link()
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = New HTMLDocument
    
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim ecoll As Object
    Dim link As Object
    Dim t As Date
    
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    t = Now()
    
    Dim reqObj As Object
    Set reqObj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        
    For i = 2 To lastrow
            
        reqObj.Open "GET", "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000), False
        reqObj.send
        
        doc.body.innerHTML = reqObj.responseText
        
    
        Set ecoll = doc.getElementById("rso")
        Set link = ecoll.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
            
        Cells(i, 2) = link.href
    Next
    
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set reqObj = Nothing
    
    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss")
    MsgBox "Ellapsed Time - " & Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

Comment: So the document does not contain an element with id "rso", or the element with id "rso" does not contain any `<a>`s. Which is either because they are not actually there, or because you don't give the document the [time to parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23299134/11683).

Comment: Maybe try to add in a delay before parsing. @GSerg might just be onto something. Oh, and would you please press ‘Debug’ to show on which line the code breaks?

Comment: Is the error happening on the exact same site it was working for previously? And I mean exact same, as @GSerg is saying, the HTML may have changed.  When it's not working, can you confirm it has the tag you're trying to capture?

Comment: Alright so this is the issue that its giving an error because it does not find that value in cell. I have tried to used the parse but i am on mistake, If it does not bother to you can you please share the solution. I would appreciated the help. 
@GSerg

Comment: on this line an error is appear `Set link = ecoll.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)`

Comment: when i was using this code earlier there was a different data set and now data is different, i understand the point of GSerg but unable to make the code correct. @BruceWayne

Comment: I cannot make it up i really do not understand what is the problem. I have tried all the available solution on the web but none of them is working. I hope you can help @Raymond Wu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hope this help you***

*Firstly*, It's appear that the `html` contenent in `reqObj.responseText` ***does not contain*** any element with id **"rso"** at all.

*Further more*, the response coming to `vba`  from "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" is not the same that presented in `browser`.

So, I try to do some tricks to catch the first search result showed on google.

For example, with the keyword "BakPhysio" we get this one.

[image]

At this point we can get the link **Description** in the  using

```
.getElementsByTagName("H3")(0).innerText
```

In the other hand, **URL** link is located near `href` section, we catch it using `substring` between "`url?q=`" and "`&`"

This following `VBA` code should give you some results.

```
Sub link()
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = New HTMLDocument
    
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim ecoll As Object
    Dim Link As Object
    Dim t As Date
    
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    t = Now()
    
    Dim reqObj As Object
    Set reqObj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        reqObj.Open "GET", "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & _
        Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000), False
        reqObj.send
                
        doc.body.innerHTML = reqObj.responseText
        
        
        
      Set all_link = doc.getElementsByTagName("A")
      Dim html, description, Url As String
      Dim start_position, end_position As Integer
      

           For j = 1 To 20 'all_link.Length - 1
              html = all_link(j).outerHTML
              
              If InStr(LCase(html), LCase("/url?q=")) Then
               start_position = InStr(html, "http")
               end_position = InStr(html, "&")
               Url = Mid(html, start_position, end_position - start_position)
                
                    If InStr(LCase(html), LCase("<h3")) Then
                      description = all_link(j).getElementsByTagName("h3")(0).innerText
                      MsgBox description & vbNewLine & Url
                      Cells(i, 2) = Url
                      j = 20 ' Once catching the 1st link, FOR loop is skipped
                End If
              End If
    
           Next j
    Next i
    
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set reqObj = Nothing
    
    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss")
    MsgBox "Ellapsed Time - " & Format(Now() - t, "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub
```

**[Result]**

[image]

Comment: Thank you but i am receiving these links instead of as your picture have https://imgur.com/m4p99ax

Comment: @Rajput, Thanks for the feedback. I fixed this issue, the code is  EDITED  by adding this line:               j = 20 ' Once catching the 1st link, FOR loop is skipped.

Comment: Thank you very much its working great.

Answer (score 2):

There is cookie consent required, or else you get don't get the expected search results; and the html, at least for me, is different. It was sufficient for me to add the following headers:

```
reqObj.setRequestHeader "cookie", "CONSENT=YES+"
reqObj.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
```

Then I needed a different ID of:

```
Set ecoll = doc.getElementById("main")
```

Your mileage may vary.

Then you need to target the `a` tags with more discrimination, or you will get a lot of stuff you almost certainly don't want.

So, try removing:

```
Set link = ecoll.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
```

And then use this:

```
Cells(i, 2) = Replace$(ecoll.querySelector("[href*=url]").href, "about:/url?q=", vbNullString)
```

Comment: Same problem is appearing, but it is giving some search result but that is not web link as i need. @QHarr https://imgur.com/a/CF4OiOH

Comment: Try the above edit.

Comment: Apologies for being late, But when i added these changes to code problem was still same error was appearing on this line. `Cells(i, 2) = Replace$(ecoll.querySelector("[href*=url]").href, "about:/url?q=", vbNullString)` https://imgur.com/IOb5JZJ

Comment: You didn't change the line above. `Set ecoll = doc.getElementById("main")`

Comment: Sir error is popping up on the same line https://imgur.com/YSARXOZ

Comment: You need to click debug and show the highlighted line. My guess is you are using a very old Office version. I ran the code and it worked fine.

Comment: https://imgur.com/undefined Sir here is the line where error is occur. I am using Excel 2016

Comment: Link doesn't work