# Extract element from html document with vba excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have this code below from HTML document, result of inspection object from site web.
I want to get the object `<input name="username" value="">` with VBA Excel code.

```html
<tr id="username_block"> 
    <td class="shade" width="50%" align="right"> 
        <div align="left">Nom d’utilisateur:</div>
    </td>
    <td class="shade" width="50%"> 
        <input name="username" value="">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I use this instruction

```vb
set element=oIe.Document.getElementsById("username_block")
```

but no results (`element`=`nothing`).

Comment: Can you expand on your code? What is `ole` and where is it defined?

Comment: Did you [wait for the page to load](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23299134/11683) before doing that?

Comment: the object id="username_block" and name="username"

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the method's name `getElementById`, without "s"?

Comment: It is. And this is most probably the issue here. Well spotted. :)