# Input text to search box on web page and click Search

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to input data from Excel workbook to web pages search field and click search button. A lot of different approaches has been tested with success. Current solution gives 424 Error, Object required. Pointing to:

```
.Document.getElementById("crmGrid_findCriteria").Value = _
      Sheets("Other data").Range("A2").Value
```

HTML for search field:

```
<input id="crmGrid_findCriteria" title="Search for records" hintlabelid="crmGrid_findHintText" type="text" class="ms-crm-Dialog-Lookup-QuickFind" maxlength="100" tabindex="0" value="">
```

HTML for Search button:

```
<img id="crmGrid_findCriteriaImg" src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif" class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-search " imgbase="/_imgs/search" title="Start search" alt="Start search">
```

Here is structure:

[image]

Here is my VBA (link for CRM system so it is not public):

```
Sub GoToOpport()

    'This will load a webpage in IE
    Dim ieappIE As InternetExplorerObject
    Dim HWNDSrc As Long
    Dim elementsSet AsappIE Object= CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    Set ie = Nothing With appIE
    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium      
    ie.Visible = True

    ie.Navigate "https://crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?area=nav_oppts&etc=3&page=SFA&pageType=EntityList&web=true"

    With ie

    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE   
    End With

ie.Document.getElementById("contentIFrame0").contentDocument.getElementById("crmGrid_findCriteria").Value = "hello"

    'Unload IE
    Set ieappIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked whether `ie.Document.getElementById("crmGrid_findCriteria") Is Nothing`? Have you tried using an explicit reference to the workbook to which `Sheets("Other data")` belongs?

Comment: Depending on what your goal is, have you considered `XmlHttpRequest`?

Comment: Additionally, does the search box loads via ajax after page load?

Comment: Have a read of [this]9https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925206/automation-error-when-getting-readystate-of-internetexplorer-object). Specially **Jean-François Corbett** answer

Comment: @Zac yes. I had it like `Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` but then I get Automation error and can not use `ie.ReadyState`

Comment: Do you still get a 424 if you step through with F8?

Comment: @QHarr yes, still 424. Also I have to use Frame source and not Page source to see source code. I don't know if this is affecting automation somehow?

Comment: what do you mean that? Is your element within a frame/iframe?

Comment: @QHarr yes, search box is inside frame. For example in Chrome if I use "View page source" I can't see search box in source code but if I choose "View frame source" I can point search box with code in my original question.

Comment: ie.document.getElementsByName("frameName")(0).document.getElementById("crmGrid_findCriteria")

Comment: ^ something like that where you use name of frame? Or use getElementsByTag("frame")(yourIndexGoesHere).document.getElementById("crmGrid_findCriteria")

Comment: @QHarr I have added structure to original question. Maybe it will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in an iframe so you need to access that

```
ie.document.getElementById("contentIFrame0").contentDocument.getElementById("crmGrid_findCriteria")
```

You can use js to attempt to assign value

```
ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "document.getElementById('contentIFrame0').document.getElementById('scrmGrid_findCriteria').value = 'hello';"
```

---

You could also try navigating to the src of the iframe

```
ie.navigate2 ie.document.querySelector("#crmContentPanel").src
 While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend 
With ie.document.getElementById("crmGrid_findCriteria")
    .focus
    .value = "abc"
End With
```

Comment: Check that contentIFrame0 is the correct id against the source

Comment: Now I don't receive any error and process goes forward. However search field is empty for some reason. I have checked that `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other data").Range("A2").Value` has value.

Comment: Step through with f8 with windows side by side and see if value actually gets input into box first and let me know

Comment: I have went through the code with F8 and there are no errors also value is not inputted to search box for some reason.

Comment: ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "document.getElementById('contentIFrame0').document.getElementById('scrmGrid_findCriteria').searchTerm.value = 'hello';"

Comment: ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "document.getElementById('contentIFrame0').document.getElementById('scrmGrid_findCriteria').value = 'hello';"

Comment: I have simplified the code (edited my original question) and now after running it with F8 and ensuring everything is loaded I am getting an error provided in original question. Tried all the solutions. I guess the problem is in iframe and scrmGrid_findCriteria access?

Comment: After moving `ie.Document.getElementById("contentIFrame0").contentDocument.getElementById("crmGrid_findCriteria").Value = "hello"`out of `With ie` it worked. Edited in my original question as it working now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a `301 Moved Permanently` status when I send a GET request and then I'm redirected here:

> https://dynamics.microsoft.com/en-us/crm/what-is-crm/

The `id="crmGrid_findCriteria"` is nowhere to be found in the HTML response, so my guess is that if you try:

```
debug.print ie.Document.getElementById("crmGrid_findCriteria") Is Nothing
```

you'll get `TRUE` as a result.

In other words, the element you're looking for doesn't exist in the HTML you downloaded.