# Print an HTML file with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, printing

I have been researching this for some time and I have come up with the following code.  However, I keep getting an error.  See below.
The intent of this code is to produce an HTML document.  Then it opens and prints the document from a printer.  I have gotten the file to save successfully and even open it in an IE window.  Then I get the error.

```
Function generateResults()
    Dim resultsBrowser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set resultsBrowser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim resultsPath As String
    Dim resultsFile As String

    resultsPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\As-Run Test Results"

    If Len(Dir(resultsPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir resultsPath
    End If

    resultsFile = resultsPath & "\As-Run " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy hmmss") & ".html"

    Open resultsFile For Output As #1
    Print #1, "<html><title>Test</title><body>Hello World</body></html>"
    Close #1

    resultsBrowser.Navigate resultsFile

    Do While resultsBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    resultsBrowser.Stop

    resultsBrowser.ExecWB 7, 1

    resultsBrowser.Quit

    Set resultsBrowser = Nothing
End Function
```

Here is the error message.

[image: Error Message]

When I go to debug, the VBA debugger points to the following line:

```
resultsBrowser.ExecWB 7, 1
```

What am I doing wrong?  My research shows that this works for others, but it does not seem to work for me.  Another oddity is that if I navigate to about:blank instead of the HTML file and comment out the ReadyState check loop, a blank Print Preview comes up successfully.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to say `Do While resultsBrowser.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE`.  Otherwise, I can confirm that this code works on my end.  Can you say anything more about your environment?  Under what context are you running this?

Comment: You need to use `InternetExplorerMedium` instead of `InternetExplorer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `InternetExplorerMedium` instead of `InternetExplorer`, as in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19221313/6201755

(As a note, to make this clear for future users, the `SHDocVw` object is contained in the **Microsoft Internet Controls** reference library, make sure to add this reference in the VBE.)

Also as the comment above, this `Do While resultsBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE` line makes it loop infinitely, so you need to change it to `<>`.

Here is the working code:

```
Private Sub test()

    Dim resultsBrowser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
    Set resultsBrowser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim resultsPath As String
    Dim resultsFile As String

    resultsPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\As-Run Test Results"

    If Len(Dir(resultsPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir resultsPath
    End If

    resultsFile = resultsPath & "\As-Run " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy hmmss") & ".html"

    Open resultsFile For Output As #1
    Print #1, "<html><title>Test</title><body>Hello World</body></html>"
    Close #1

    resultsBrowser.Navigate resultsFile

    Do While resultsBrowser.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    resultsBrowser.Stop

    resultsBrowser.ExecWB 7, 1

    resultsBrowser.Quit

    Set resultsBrowser = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  This worked perfectly.  Thanks for the catch on the infinite loop.  I had actually been running with that commented out in case it was causing an issue.  Probably why I did not notice.