# internetexplorer.application object raises an "Automation error - unknown interface" error on a given link

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

The following code snippet usually works to create an Internet Explorer instance and navigate a link:

```
Dim appIE As Object
Dim myLink As String: myLink = "www.something.com"

Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
With appIE
  .Navigate myLink
  .Visible = True
End With
```

The problem is that, depending on the link (`myLink`), the page is navigated but then the interface becomes unknown and the object `appIE` contains no variable.

For example, if

```
myLink = "https://www.facebook.com"
```

... the object `appIE` shows the Facebook login page and can be used by the code (i.e. if I add a watcher, I can see all the properties of the object.
However, if the link is:

```
myLink = "https://mxjira.murex.com/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=2030&view=detail&cb=7055"
```

... the object `appIE` raises an "unknown interface" error and, seen by the watcher, this object contains no variable.

The link above is protected (it's an internal page of my company), but should still give an idea of the issue. 
The browser, with `appIE.Visible = True`, is actually showing the webpage. Why is the object losing all its variables then? How can I fix this "unknown interface" issue, where is it coming from if I can see the content of the webpage in the browser I just created?

Comment: check the `.readystate` and `.busy` of the IE, it could be loading something that's taking time/not working.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav done, the status is ready (4).

Comment: is it busy?    Check that as well.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav actually, the issue is that appIE basically doesn't exist anymore after having navigated the link. I can't access neither appIE.busy nor other properties, I can just check the readystate directly on the browser that has been created but not from the VBA IDE itself.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965032/excel-vba-controlling-ie-local-intranet

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yes, but still the same issue. Once I navigate that page, my variable appIE basically becomes empty (it's not "Nothing", but it's just empty - unknown, as it says). Hence, I can't apply the checks described there.

Comment: have you tried using inernetexploremedim as discussed in the post.

Comment: Hello @Nathan_Sav, I finally solved the issue using the internetexplorermedium! Would you like to write it as an answer so that I can accept it and close the thread? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the following

[Excel VBA Controlling IE local intranet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965032/excel-vba-controlling-ie-local-intranet)

If you use InternetExplorerMedium instead of InternetExplorer, it should correct your issue.

Thanks.

Nathan.