# IE.Document.Frames("frame_name") fails while Set IEDoc -> IEDoc.Frames works

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, ie-automation

I'm trying to set a final target frame in one line, but somehow IE.Document works only if it's assigned to a variable.

So the following statement works:

```
Set IEDoc = IE.Document
Set objFrameMain = IEDoc.frames("frame_name")
```

while this one fails with Automation error:

```
Set objFrameMain = IE.Document.frames("frame_name")
```

Why could it be so?

Comment: If you're working on an intra-net (which I guess it's the case since you're not sharing a reproducible test case), I recently had a [similar experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45793222/internetexplorer-application-object-raises-an-automation-error-unknown-interf/45819435#45819435). Maybe you're being able to set `objFrameMain`, but I guess it's `Nothing` and not really what you want. Try to use the type `InternetExplorerMedium` instead of `InternetExplorer` and check if it solves it, but the error you describe above doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, i don't think that it makes any difference whether he is on intranet. if the first two lines work, then the single line should work also. ...... wait a minute .... maybe it is the execution time that makes a difference

Comment: do you have a _loop while IE busy_?

Comment: @jsotola well it doesn't work even in step by step pace in debug mode.

Comment: add `IE.Document.frames` into the _Watch window_  ... just highlight it and drag to _Watch window_ .... put a breakpoint at `Set IEDoc = IE.Document` and run. ... examine the   `IE.Document.frames` object in _Watch window_ ... is it still _Nothing_ ?

Comment: see if this throws an error  `Debug.Print IE.Document.frames.Length`

Comment: @jsotola that's what I thought too, but it's not the case. Intranet servers stops providing information to the browser in a different way than public websites, with the consequence that the interface becomes unknown in the IE object itself very easily when you're on an intranet.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ, well, thanks to addressing my problem, I choose to proceed with addressing the frame after addressing IE.Doc, setting it to variable one by one.
Though i'm still confused, why nested syntax (IE.Document.Frame('x').Document) doesn't work.

Comment: @jsotola, same for you. Thanks!