# Scraping the data from list of href link?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, href

I am trying to scrap a list of href link from a webpage, and then trying to scrap the value out of it. I am now facing the problem which the code only can handle up to 5 links. If the links more than 5, it will show runtime error on random line.

I am extracting the href link from these webpage:http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/#/?category=SH&sub_category=all&alphabetical=All&date_from=28/09/2018

```
Option Explicit
Sub ScrapLink()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With IE

        IE.Visible = False
        IE.navigate Cells(1, 1).Value

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
        Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to website?"
        DoEvents

        Dim links As Object, i As Long
        Set links = .document.querySelectorAll("#bm_ajax_container [href^='/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/']")
        For i = 1 To links.Length
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                .Cells(i + 1, 1) = links.item(i - 1)
            End With
        Next i
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, headers(), u As Long, resultCollection As Collection
    headers = Array("URL", "Name", "No", "Date of change", "# Securities", "Type of Transaction", "Nature of Interest")
    Set resultCollection = New Collection
    Dim links()
    links = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A100"))

    With IE
        .Visible = True

        For u = LBound(links) To UBound(links)
            If InStr(links(u), "http") > 0 Then
                .navigate links(u)

                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
                Dim data As Object, title As Object

                With .document.getElementById("bm_ann_detail_iframe").contentDocument
                    Set title = .querySelector(".formContentData")
                    Set data = .querySelectorAll(".ven_table tr")
                End With

                Dim results(), numberOfRows As Long, i As Long, currentRow As Object, td As Object, c As Long, r As Long

                numberOfRows = Round(data.Length / 4, 0)
                ReDim results(1 To numberOfRows, 1 To 7)

                For i = 0 To numberOfRows - 1
                    r = i + 1
                    results(r, 1) = links(u): results(r, 2) = title.innerText
                    Set currentRow = data.item(i * 4 + 1)
                    c = 3
                    For Each td In currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                        results(r, c) = Replace$(td.innerText, "document.write(rownum++);", vbNullString)
                        c = c + 1
                    Next td
                Next i
                resultCollection.Add results
                Set data = Nothing: Set title = Nothing
            End If
        Next u
        .Quit
    End With
    Dim ws As Worksheet, item As Long
    If Not resultCollection.Count > 0 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Evaluate("ISREF('Results'!A1)") Then  '<==Credit to @Rory for this test
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add
        ws.NAME = "Results"
    Else
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
        ws.Cells.Clear
    End If

    Dim outputRow As Long: outputRow = 2
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        For item = 1 To resultCollection.Count
            Dim arr()
            arr = resultCollection(item)
            For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
                .Cells(outputRow, 1).Resize(1, 7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, i, 0)
                outputRow = outputRow + 1
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Discussion:**

The problem is likely, at least from my testing, due to one of the links not having the table `Details of changes`, so the `numberOfRows` variable is set to `0`, and this line:

```
ReDim results(1 To numberOfRows, 1 To 7)
```

fails with an index error as you have `(1 To 0, 1 To 7)`.

Using [this link](http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/#/?category=SH&sub_category=all&alphabetical=All) in A1 there are 30 URLs retrieved. This retrieved [link](http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/5927801) does not have that table whereas the others do.

You have a choice of how to handle this scenario. Here are some example options:

**Option 1:** Only process the page if the `numberOfRows > 0`. This is the example I give.

**Option 2:** Have a `Select Case` with `numberOfRows` and if `Case 0` then handle page in one way, `Case Else` handle as normal.

---

**Note:**

1) You also want to reset the status bar with:

```
Application.StatusBar = False
```

2) I temporarily fixed the links range for testing with:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A31")
```

---

**TODO:**

1. Refactor to be more modular and run the whole process with the same IE instance. Creating a class to hold the IE object would be a good idea. Provide it with methods for extracting your data, testing number of result rows etc.
2. Add some basic error handling, for example, to handle failed website connection.

---

**Example handling using test of numberOfRows > 0:**

```
Option Explicit
Sub ScrapeLink()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With IE
        IE.Visible = True
        IE.navigate Cells(1, 1).Value

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
       ' Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
        Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to website?"
        DoEvents

        Dim links As Object, i As Long
        Set links = .document.querySelectorAll("#bm_ajax_container [href^='/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/']")
        For i = 1 To links.Length
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                .Cells(i + 1, 1) = links.item(i - 1)
            End With
        Next i
        .Quit
    End With
    Application.StatusBar = false
End Sub

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, headers(), u As Long, resultCollection As Collection
    headers = Array("URL", "Name", "No", "Date of change", "# Securities", "Type of Transaction", "Nature of Interest")
    Set resultCollection = New Collection
    Dim links()
    links = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A31")) '<== I have fixed the range here for testing 

    With IE
        .Visible = True

        For u = LBound(links) To UBound(links)
            If InStr(links(u), "http") > 0 Then
                .navigate links(u)

                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
                Dim data As Object, title As Object

                With .document.getElementById("bm_ann_detail_iframe").contentDocument
                    Set title = .querySelector(".formContentData")
                    Set data = .querySelectorAll(".ven_table tr")
                End With

                Dim results(), numberOfRows As Long, i As Long, currentRow As Object, td As Object, c As Long, r As Long

                numberOfRows = Round(data.Length / 4, 0)

                If numberOfRows > 0 Then

                    ReDim results(1 To numberOfRows, 1 To 7)

                    For i = 0 To numberOfRows - 1
                        r = i + 1
                        results(r, 1) = links(u): results(r, 2) = title.innerText
                        Set currentRow = data.item(i * 4 + 1)
                        c = 3
                        For Each td In currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                            results(r, c) = Replace$(td.innerText, "document.write(rownum++);", vbNullString)
                            c = c + 1
                        Next td
                    Next i
                    resultCollection.Add results
                    Set data = Nothing: Set title = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        Next u
        .Quit
    End With
    Dim ws As Worksheet, item As Long
    If Not resultCollection.Count > 0 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Evaluate("ISREF('Results'!A1)") Then  '<==Credit to @Rory for this test
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add
        ws.NAME = "Results"
    Else
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
        ws.Cells.Clear
    End If

    Dim outputRow As Long: outputRow = 2
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        For item = 1 To resultCollection.Count
            Dim arr()
            arr = resultCollection(item)
            For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
                .Cells(outputRow, 1).Resize(1, 7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, i, 0)
                outputRow = outputRow + 1
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Sample results:**

[image]

Comment: Hi,QHarr the code show "run-time error'-2147023179automation error the interface is unknown" on the line  While .Busy Or .readyState < 4:

Comment: Hi, Very weird as we know if works from before. See if this keeps happening. If it does then change to using Dim IE As New InternetExplorerMedium and see if that fixes it and let me know.

Comment: ya, it worked last time but when i rerun the code, the error occurs. I will try it first.Thank you.

Comment: This is the InternetExplorerMedium reference I was thinking of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965032/excel-vba-controlling-ie-local-intranet

Comment: now there is an error of "Method RegisterAsBrowser of object IWebBrowser2 failed". I realized everytime I run the the code, the webpage loaded but it could not proceed to the next url. I guess that   the url navigation process stuck in the middle.

Comment: Can you open task manager and just make sure your Internet Explorer instances have been closed properly first?

Comment: Can you also try changing .Navigate to .Navigate2 with InternetExplorer (not InternetExplorerMedium)

Comment: now i am facing another problem, whatever link i input, the IE just load the homepages. For example, when i input these url: http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/#/?category=SB&sub_category=all&alphabetical=All&date_from=01/10/2018,it end up opening these url:              http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/#/?category=all

Comment: If you put the link physically into the browser what happens?

Comment: it seem the problem still there. I have to restart my pc in order to get it run well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181072/discussion-between-qharr-and-hong-yew).