# getElementById - the remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to navigate on a online server with below code but for some reason, I get the error that the server does not exist or is unavailable. The page opens so I guess it has access but it fails to navigate? Any suggestions on why it is failing and how to fix it?
I tested the code on a normal website and it works in that case.

```
Sub URL_Nav()

'Dim obJIE As Object

Set obJIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

obJIE.Visible = True


obJIE.Navigate2 ("http://...")

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

obJIE.document.getElementById("docTypeForm:documentTypesTbl:137:n").Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally found the solution :)

`Set obJIE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")`

Here you can find the explanation, it will use InternetExplorerMedium through the class:
[Controlling Internet Explorer local intranet using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965032/controlling-internet-explorer-local-intranet-using-excel-vba)